# Javascript is 100 faster than Classical C in simple for loop test, why?

Tags: javascript, c

How `JavaScript` could do much faster than `C` for the following simple for loop example. It's almost  **100 times** faster than `C` after I tested those two codes. How `JavaScript` do string concatenation faster than `C` in the loop? Somebody said `JavaScript` is ***heavy dynamic language*** and it change variable, function on run-time, What's that meaning ?
From the `console.log` or `printf` for str variable, it proved the for-loop is executed
in both code without any compiler optimization that I guess.

JavaScript Loop Time: **205ms**
C loop time: **32500ms**

javascript:

```js
 var i, a, b, c, max,str;
 max = 2e5;
 str="";
 var a = new Date();
 var myvar =   Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(),a.getMonth(),a.getDay(),a.getHours(),a.getMinutes(),a.getSeconds(),a.getMilliseconds());
 for (i=0;i< max;i++) {
     str= str+i+"=";  //just concat string
 }
 var a = new Date();
 var myvar2 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(),a.getMonth(),a.getDay(),a.getHours(),a.getMinutes(),a.getSeconds(),a.getMilliseconds());
 console.log("loop time:",myvar2-myvar);  //show for-loop time
 console.log("str:",str);  //for checking the for-loop is executed or not
```

classical c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    int i, a, b, c, max;
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();
    max = 2e5;
    char f[9];
    char str[10000000] = {""};
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        sprintf(f, "%ld", i); // convert integer to string
        strcat(str, "="); // just concat
        strcat(str, f);
    } // just concat
    t2 = clock();
    float diff = (((float)t2 - (float)t1) / 1000000.0F) * 1000;
    printf("loop time output in ms= :%.2fms\n", diff); // show for-loop time
    printf("str:%s\n", str); // check whether the for loop is executed or not
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So where are your benchmarks backing up your claim? What compiler flags did you pass when compiling the C? How many iterations of each test did you do? You need to post a bunch more detail in your question

Comment: Take the sprintf(f, "%ld",i); out of the C loop and you result will change.

Comment: I do it my linux vsp server, it is 2e5 iteritions and I run javascript code on nodejs

Comment: Why? Because `strcat()` is expensive. Do not use it in a (extensive long) loop. This is true for most of the members of the `str*()`-family of functions. Optimising code for use-cases as yours needs different approaches in C. See *pmg*'s answer for a possible approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25629106/694576

Comment: In the C code, divide the difference between `t1` and `t2` by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to get the elapsed time in seconds, then scale that to ms.  Note that `clock()` doesn't necessarily give you microsecond resolution.

Comment: To the downvoters: I feel this is not a bad question. It has everything a question needs. Being a C-rookie question does not make it a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Javascript is 100 faster than Classical C in simple for loop test, why?

**Because C does not have strings in the same sense javascript has.**

To make the test more fair, do these changes:

Outside the loop add

```
char *strptr;
strptr = str;
```

and replace the loop with

```
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    strptr += sprintf(strptr, "=%d", i);
}
```

Of course now, after these changes, the javascript version may be doing more work than the C version. C has no buffer overflow checks. The javascript version, apparently, is checking the size of the string and expanding it when needed.

Comment: but my C code is working and output is correct on str variable

Comment: pmg, why I could not get the output from  printf("s:%s\n", strptr)? supoose it should be "s:=1=2=3=4......199999"

Comment: use `printf("s:%s\n", str);`; `strptr` points to the end of the string.

Comment: I use strptr, it show str:170245552=170245552....all number is same ,why ? it seems the for-loop is not executed

Comment: sorry typing I used str already.How to show it all as I did on javascript code?

Comment: print `str` instead of `strptr`

Comment: do not change references to `str` in other parts of your code. Replace just the loop and add just the 2 lines.

Comment: now I use printf("str:%s\n",str); but it doesn't work

Comment: #include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(){
int  i, a, b, c, max;
clock_t t1 ,t2;
t1=clock();
max = 2e5;
char f[9];
char str[10000000]={""};
char *strptr;
strptr = str;

for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    sprintf(f, "%ld", i);
    strptr += sprintf(strptr, "=%d", str, f);
}

t2=clock();
float diff = (((float)t2 - (float)t1) / 1000000.0F ) * 1000;
printf("loop time output in ms= :%.2fms\n",diff); //show for-loop time
printf("str:%s\n",str);    //check whether the for loop is executed or not
return 0;
 }

Comment: Do you realize the length of the output is (approx) `1288890` characters long?

Comment: It works in [ideone](http://ideone.com/JY7TZg) *loop time: 0.01ms*. You may want to move the very large array outside the function, to global scope ... or use `malloc()` and friends

Comment: Sorry, my error I forgot to comment some lines. yes, it is correct on your code

Comment: You're welcome @aabb. Just remember C strings and javascript strings are completely different beasts. You can't really compare execution time of *stringy* programs as if they were similar.